# Падает ошибка ERROR TypeError: Invalid event target

Tags: angular

При первоначальной загрузке падает ошибка ERROR TypeError: Invalid event target. В чем может быть причина?

```
<div class="action" (click)="createTextComponent()" #elementRef>
  <icon-text [config]="iconsConfigText" [hoveredElement]="elementRef"></icon-text>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

```
@Input() hoveredElement: HTMLDivElement;

ngAfterViewInit() {
 const divMouseenter$ = fromEvent(this.hoveredElement, 'mouseenter').pipe(
      tap(_ => {
        this.isActive = true;
        this.detectChanges();
      })
    )

    const divMouseleave$ = fromEvent(this.hoveredElement, 'mouseleave').pipe(
      tap(_ => {
        this.isActive = false;
        this.detectChanges();
      })
    )

    merge(divMouseenter$, divMouseleave$).pipe(
      untilComponentDestroyed(this),
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

Comment: создай пример на codesandbox, ты явно делаешь что-то не так. Я проверил локально и у меня все работает

Comment: https://angular-w679ms.stackblitz.io/ вырезал из проекта, но здесь invalid event target не падает